# Problema con una función que tiene que mezclar arreglos

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucle-for, condiciones

me encuentro haciendo un ejercicio en el que tengo que crear una función que le entre como parámetro dos arreglos y esta los tiene que mezclar de uno en uno, esto es lo que tengo hecho:

```
  function mezclarArreglos ([array], [array2]) {
let array3 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array.length || i < array2.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] != undefined && array2[i] != undefined) {
    array3 = array3.push(array[i], array2[i]);
  } else if (array != undefined) {
    array3 = array3.push(array[i]);
  } else {
    array3 = array3.push(array2[i])
  }
}
  console.log(array3);
```

};

El problema de esto es que cuando lo pruebo en la consola me sale el primer carácter del primer array, por ejemplo, mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],['h','o','l','a']) devuelve 1 cuando tendria que devolver  [1, “h”, 2,”o”, 3,”l”,4,”a”]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razon por la que no te funciona es porque tienes los parametros puestos de esta forma:

```
function mezclarArreglos ([array], [array2]) {

}
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando haces destructuring en parametros que son arreglos, estas sacando cada uno de sus valores para usarlos directamente, en tu caso siempre estabas sacando es solo el primer valor, me explico:

```js
function mezclarArreglos ([valor1, valor2], [valor3, valor4]) {
    return [valor1, valor2];
}

console.log(mezclarArreglos([1, 2], [3, 4]));
```

Es por eso que te retornaba **1**, ahora bien, quice plantear lo que hiciste de otra forma, para ello me he ayudado de un ciclo `forEach` y he organizado un poco mejor el asunto, sin usar parametros destructurados de esta manera:

```js
function mezclarArreglos(array, array2) {
  let bigger = array.length < array2.length ? array2 : array;
  let res = [];
  
  bigger.forEach((el, i)=>{
    if(array[i]) res.push(array[i]);
    if(array2[i]) res.push(array2[i]);
  });
  
  return res;
}

console.log(mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],['h','o','l','a']));
```

Lo que hacemos es:

```
let bigger = array.length < array2.length ? array2 : array;
```

Primero almacenamos cual de los dos arreglos es el mayor (cual tiene mas elementos), con base a eso vamos a iterar ese arreglo.

```
bigger.forEach((el, i)=>{
  if(array[i]) res.push(array[i]);
  if(array2[i]) res.push(array2[i]);
});
```

Iteramos el arreglo mas grande y con ayuda de nuestro indice `i` comprobamos en cada iteracion si el primer arreglo (`array`) esta definido en el indice `i`, si es asi significa que hay valores, por lo tanto añadimos al arreglo `res` ese elemento.

Esto mismo lo comprobamos pero con `array2` mas abajo, de esta forma el orden para anadir los elementos siempre sera el primer arreglo + el segundo.

Estas comprobaciones son necesarias porque si no quiza estemos añadiendo 'basura' a nuestro arreglo final, el cual contiene el resultado de mezclar ambos arreglos como lo necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta con for e if

### Incluye la posibilidad de que los array sean de longitudes distintas

```
function mezclarArreglos(arr, arr1) {
let arrRes = [];
for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  if (arr[index]!=undefined)  {arrRes.push(arr[index])}
  if (arr1[index]!=undefined) {arrRes.push(arr1[index])}   
}
console.log (arrRes)
}    
mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4], ['h','p']);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).